# Convergence in probability question

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

I'm looking for help with this question.

Let (X$_n$), where n ∈ $\mathbb{N}$, be a sequence of random variables defined on a probability space (Ω,$\mathcal{F}$,$\mathbb{P}$).
Show that if X$_n$ converges to a ∈ $\mathbb{R}$ almost surely as n → ∞, then it also converges in
probability to a as n → ∞.

I have a couple of questions. Does the phrase 'almost surely' mean anything in particular within statistics? The other question I had was what it means by 'converges in probability'. I understand convergence but am unsure what it means by this.

Thank you!!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_probability gives the definition for converges in probability.

To your other question, 'almost surely' means except perhaps on a set of measure zero. It is analogous to measure theory's 'almost everywhere'

Comment: almost surely is completely unrelated to an statistic